# serverless function can be deployed on AWS, invoked locall but not on found on AWS

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I'm a bit puzzled and would really appreciate some help. I'm new to serverless and would like to play around with it a bit. I've followed this [tutorial](https://serverless.com/blog/serverless-python-packaging/) to setup a serverless test function.

I've also mentioned to deploy my function to AWS:

```
ola@pad:~/projects/serverless$ sls deploy --stage dev --aws-profile numpy-serverless-agent
Serverless: Packaging service...
Serverless: Excluding development dependencies...
Serverless: Injecting required Python packages to package...
Serverless: Uploading CloudFormation file to S3...
Serverless: Uploading artifacts...
Serverless: Uploading service numpy-test.zip file to S3 (6.41 KB)...
Serverless: Validating template...
Serverless: Updating Stack...
Serverless: Checking Stack update progress...
.......
Serverless: Stack update finished...
Service Information
service: numpy-test
stage: dev
region: us-east-1
stack: numpy-test-dev
resources: 5
api keys:
  None
endpoints:
  None
functions:
  test: numpy-test-dev-test
layers:
  None
ola@pad:~/projects/serverless$
```

Invoking locally works perfect:

```
ola@pad:~/projects/serverless$ sls invoke local --f test
Your numpy array:

[[ 0  1  2  3  4]
 [ 5  6  7  8  9]
 [10 11 12 13 14]]
null
ola@pad:~/projects/serverless$
```

However invoking on AWS failes as the function is not found:

```
ola@pad:~/projects/serverless$ sls invoke --f test

  Serverless Error ---------------------------------------

  Function not found: arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:XXXXXXXX:function:numpy-test-dev-test

  Get Support --------------------------------------------
     Docs:          docs.serverless.com
     Bugs:          github.com/serverless/serverless/issues
     Issues:        forum.serverless.com

  Your Environment Information -----------------------------
     OS:                     linux
     Node Version:           10.15.1
     Serverless Version:     1.37.1
```

Finally here is my serverless.yml file

```
# Welcome to Serverless!
#
# This file is the main config file for your service.
# It's very minimal at this point and uses default values.
# You can always add more config options for more control.
# We've included some commented out config examples here.
# Just uncomment any of them to get that config option.
#
# For full config options, check the docs:
#    docs.serverless.com
#
# Happy Coding!

service: numpy-test

# You can pin your service to only deploy with a specific Serverless version
# Check out our docs for more details
# frameworkVersion: "=X.X.X"

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.6
  stage: dev
  region: us-east-1


plugins:
  - serverless-python-requirements

custom:
  pythonRequirements:
    dockerizePip: true

# you can overwrite defaults here

# you can define service wide environment variables here
#  environment:
#    variable1: value1

# you can add packaging information here
package:
#  include:
#    - include-me.py
#    - include-me-dir/**
  exclude:
    - node_modules/**

functions:
  test:
    handler: handler.test

#    The following are a few example events you can configure
#    NOTE: Please make sure to change your handler code to work with those events
#    Check the event documentation for details
#    events:
#      - http:
#          path: users/create
#          method: get
#      - websocket: $connect
#      - s3: ${env:BUCKET}
#      - schedule: rate(10 minutes)
#      - sns: greeter-topic
#      - stream: arn:aws:dynamodb:region:XXXXXX:table/foo/stream/1970-01-01T00:00:00.000
#      - alexaSkill: amzn1.ask.skill.xx-xx-xx-xx
#      - alexaSmartHome: amzn1.ask.skill.xx-xx-xx-xx
#      - iot:
#          sql: "SELECT * FROM 'some_topic'"
#      - cloudwatchEvent:
#          event:
#            source:
#              - "aws.ec2"
#            detail-type:
#              - "EC2 Instance State-change Notification"
#            detail:
#              state:
#                - pending
#      - cloudwatchLog: '/aws/lambda/hello'
#      - cognitoUserPool:
#          pool: MyUserPool
#          trigger: PreSignUp

#    Define function environment variables here
#    environment:
#      variable2: value2

# you can add CloudFormation resource templates here
#resources:
#  Resources:
#    NewResource:
#      Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
#      Properties:
#        BucketName: my-new-bucket
#  Outputs:
#     NewOutput:
#       Description: "Description for the output"
#       Value: "Some output value"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When deploying the service you used a non-default AWS profile by passing the argument `--aws-profile numpy-serverless-agent`. It means that it is deployed to the account specified by this profile.

When trying to inovke the lambda, you didn't pass this argument, thus using the default profile, which is probably specifying a different AWS account.

Comment: thanks that makes sense. how can I test invoke it with a specific aws profile?

Comment: Use the same command-line argument (it's a general one for all commands)